# Use Cursor with select and other insert, update script

Tags: oracle, select, package, cursor, procedure

I developing a oracle procedure that return data and at the same time, do some others commits on database.

But, when I try to do the insert, I can´t read the ID (return on select).

```
PROCEDURE SP_L_TODOS_CAIXASEMAIL_JOB_V2(
    IN_COD_TIPO_PSST IN INTEGER, 
    IN_COD_SITU_PSST IN INTEGER, 
    IN_NOM_ISTA_SERD IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_IND_ISTA_SERD_PSST_ATIV IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_DAT_ATVC_SERD IN DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
    IN_DAT_ULTI_ALTE_SERD IN DATE,  
    PO_RETORNO OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
L_EXISTS INTEGER := 0;
N_COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET INTEGER := 0;
N_COD_ISTA_PSST INTEGER := 0;
N_COD_PSST_CAIX_EMAI INTEGER := 0;
R_RETORNO SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    -- RETURN DATA OF 1 REG
    OPEN PO_RETORNO FOR
    SELECT T292.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET, T292.COD_ASSN_ATED, T292.COD_CANA_ORIG_ATED, T007.NOM_CANA_ORIG_ATED, T292.NOM_CAIX_ENDE_ELET, T292.DES_CAIX_ENDE_ELET, T291.COD_CELU_ATED, T009.NOM_CELU_ATED, T292.IND_RGTO_AUTA_EMAI_OCOR, T292.IND_CAIX_ENDE_ELET_ATIV, T291.IND_CAIX_CELU_ATED_ATIV, T301.DAT_PSST_CAIX_EMAI
    FROM ORABP41.TBBP4292_CAIX_EMAI_ELET T292
    LEFT JOIN ORABP41.TBBP4007_CANA_ORIG_ATED T007 
      ON T292.COD_CANA_ORIG_ATED = T007.COD_CANA_ORIG_ATED
    LEFT JOIN ORABP41.TBBP4291_CAIX_EMAI_CELU_ATED T291
      ON T292.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET = T291.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET 
    LEFT JOIN ORABP41.TBBp4009_CELU_TRAT_ATED T009   
      ON T291.COD_CELU_ATED = T009.COD_CELU_ATED
    LEFT JOIN ORABP41.TBBP4301_PSST_CAIX_EMAI T301
        ON T292.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET = T301.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET 
    WHERE T292.IND_CAIX_ENDE_ELET_ATIV = 'S' 
      AND T291.IND_CAIX_CELU_ATED_ATIV = 'S'
      AND T292.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET NOT IN (SELECT COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET FROM ORABP41.TBBP4301_PSST_CAIX_EMAI WHERE COD_SITU_PSST = 1)
      AND ROWNUM = 1
    --ORDER BY T292.NOM_CAIX_ENDE_ELET ASC;
    ORDER BY T301.DAT_PSST_CAIX_EMAI ASC;

    FOR PO_RETORNO IN R_RETORNO
    LOOP 

        -- PROCESS 01
        SELECT NVL((SELECT NVL(COD_ISTA_PSST,0) FROM ORABP41.TBBP4293_ISTA_SERD_PSST 
                WHERE NOM_ISTA_SERD = IN_NOM_ISTA_SERD AND COD_TIPO_PSST = IN_COD_TIPO_PSST AND ROWNUM = 1), 0) INTO L_EXISTS FROM DUAL;

        IF (L_EXISTS = 0) THEN

            SELECT NVL(MAX(COD_ISTA_PSST),0)+1 AS CODIGO INTO N_COD_ISTA_PSST FROM ORABP41.TBBP4293_ISTA_SERD_PSST WHERE ROWNUM =1;

            INSERT INTO ORABP41.TBBP4293_ISTA_SERD_PSST
                (COD_ISTA_PSST, COD_TIPO_PSST, NOM_ISTA_SERD, 
                IND_ISTA_SERD_PSST_ATIV, DAT_ATVC_SERD, DAT_ULTI_ALTE_SERD)
            VALUES
                (N_COD_ISTA_PSST,IN_COD_TIPO_PSST,IN_NOM_ISTA_SERD,
                IN_IND_ISTA_SERD_PSST_ATIV, IN_DAT_ATVC_SERD, IN_DAT_ULTI_ALTE_SERD);

            COMMIT; 
        END IF;

        IF (L_EXISTS != 0) THEN
            UPDATE ORABP41.TBBP4293_ISTA_SERD_PSST
            SET DAT_ULTI_ALTE_SERD = IN_DAT_ULTI_ALTE_SERD, IND_ISTA_SERD_PSST_ATIV = IN_IND_ISTA_SERD_PSST_ATIV
            WHERE NOM_ISTA_SERD = IN_NOM_ISTA_SERD AND COD_TIPO_PSST = IN_COD_TIPO_PSST;
            --RETURNING COD_ISTA_PSST INTO PO_RETORNO;

            COMMIT;
        END IF;         

        -- PROCESS 02
        SELECT NVL(MAX(COD_PSST_CAIX_EMAI),0)+1 AS CODIGO INTO N_COD_PSST_CAIX_EMAI FROM ORABP41.TBBP4301_PSST_CAIX_EMAI WHERE ROWNUM =1;

        INSERT INTO ORABP41.TBBP4301_PSST_CAIX_EMAI
            (COD_PSST_CAIX_EMAI, COD_ISTA_PSST, COD_SITU_PSST, COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET, DAT_PSST_CAIX_EMAI)
        VALUES 
            (N_COD_PSST_CAIX_EMAI, N_COD_ISTA_PSST, IN_COD_SITU_PSST, R_RETORNO.COD_CAIX_ENDE_ELET, SYSDATE);

        COMMIT;

    END LOOP; 

END;
```

I think that exists something wrong, because the compilation on database show me

Erro(81,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Erro(81,21): PLS-00221: 'R_RETORNO' não é um procedimento ou está indefinido

Comment: Your select statement. " SELECT NVL((SELECT NVL(COD_ISTA_PSST,0) ..." needs to be "select ... into L_EXISTS from ..."  Also you should not be doing all those commits in there. In fact, you probably should not do any commits in the procedure, and let the caller decide if to commit or not. There's probably other syntax error in the procedure, but hard to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I decide to change the script... I put the 1st step (select rownum =1) , and than insert, update and at the last step, I put the select cursor. It is working OK.